# sockiet.ion passport.js, express.js and authentication headers

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, socket.io, passport.js

My chrome extension was working perfectly until recently.

I originally received a error message of

```
required same site none and secure in the header
```

I then added to my express.session config,

```
 samesite:none, secure:true
```

Now instead of that error, I am unable to gain access to my website by login in with my chrome extension, which I believe is due to socket.io not maintaining the authentication cookie.

My express server is as below,

```
const config = require('../../config');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });
const mysql = require('mysql');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const ExpressMysqlSessionStore = require('express-mysql-session')(expressSession);
const sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils');

// remove from header "X-Powered-By: Express"
app.disable('x-powered-by');

server.listen(config.serverParams.port, config.serverParams.address, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`);
});

/* DATABASE */
global.db = mysql.createConnection(config.db);
db.connect();
/* DATABASE */

/* SESSION */
const sessionStore = new ExpressMysqlSessionStore(config.sessionStore, db);
const session = expressSession({
    ...config.session,
    store: sessionStore,
});
app.use(session);
/* SESSION */

app.use(express.static(config.frontendDir));

app.get([
    '/signup',
    '/stats',
    '/pay',
], (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(`${config.frontendDir}${req.path}.html`)));

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave: true
}));

io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.use((packet, next) => {
        if (packet[0]) {
            console.log('METHOD:', packet[0]);
            const sessionData = socket.handshake.session.user;
            const noSessionNeed = [ 'login', 'signup', 'checkAuth' ].includes(packet[0]);
            let error;
            if ( ! sessionData && ! noSessionNeed) error = { code: -1, message: 'You need to login in extension!' };
            if (error) return next(new Error(JSON.stringify(error)));
            else next();
        }
    });

    const auth = require('./auth')(socket);
    socket.on('checkAuth', auth.checkAuth);
    socket.on('login', auth.login);
    socket.on('signup', auth.signup);
    socket.on('logout', auth.logout);

    const users = require('./users')(socket);
    socket.on('users.get', users.get);

    const sentiment = require('./sentiment')(socket);
    socket.on('sentiment.get', sentiment.get);
    socket.on('sentiment.set', sentiment.set);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {

    });

});
```

And the config file is somewhat like this,

```
config.session = {
        // globals.config.express.sessionSecret
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
                maxAge: 86400000,
                /* FOR WORK ON LOCALHOST
                secure: true,
                sameSite: 'lax', */
                sameSite:"None",
                secure:true,
                domain: '.xx.xx',
        },
```

Here is how the authentication is done with the socket.io

```
const passport = require('passport');
/* PASSPORT */
require('./passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
/* app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); */
/* PASSPORT */

const utils = require('./utils');

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

module.exports = socket => {

    this.checkAuth = fn => {
        if (fn) fn();
    };

    this.login = (params, fn) => {
        passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, user) => {
            const response = {};
            if (user) {
                socket.handshake.session.user = user;
                socket.handshake.session.save();
                response.message = 'Your successful login!';
                response.data = {
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                };
            }
            else if (err) {
                response.error = {
                    code: err,
                    message: ''
                };
                if (err == -1) response.error.message = 'Incorrect username or password!';
            }
            if (fn) fn(response);
        })({ body: params });
    },

    // socket.on('signup', (params, fn) => {
    this.signup = (params, fn) => {
        passport.authenticate('local-signup', (err, user) => {
            const response = {};
            if (user) {
                console.log('signup', user);
                response.message = 'Your successful signup!';
            }
            else if (err) {
                response.error = {
                    code: err,
                    message: ''
                };
                if (err == -1) response.error.message = 'User alreay exist!';
            }
            if (fn) fn(response);
        })({ body: params });
    };

    // socket.on('logout', fn => {
    this.logout = fn => {
        delete socket.handshake.session.user;
    };

    return this;

};
```

utils

```
module.exports = socket => {

    // socket.on('users.get', fn => {
    this.get = fn => {
        if (fn) {
            const response = {};
            response.data = {
                id: socket.handshake.session.user.id,
                username: socket.handshake.session.user.username,
            };
            fn(response);
        }
    };

    return this;

};
```

Would love to be able to solve this issue :P

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set up cors ? This sound like a common cross origin issue.  Check out this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Yes - I've tried just setting cors, but for some reason it bugs out when re-connecting.

Comment: I had an issue before with express session not sending out the set-cookie header when my app was behind a cloudflare proxy because even though the proxy was trusted the req.secure field was false. I eventually just had my middleware send out the set-cookie header rather than relying on express-session to do it.

Comment: Yes I think that's the issue - how would you implement that logic here?

Comment: In your middleware you can do: 

res.cookie(
    'session', 
    req.sessionID, 
    {
        signed: true, 
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: 'none'
    }
); 

and force express to send out the set-cookie header for express-session

Comment: Could you write that up as an answer, with how it would integrate into the above code? I'm thinking, i'd use cors library, then try and implement what it is you are saying?

Comment: Unfortunately you're handling auth in socket-io and I'm not quite sure of the interface for interacting with cookies through socket-io. I did find a library that apparently handles auth in socket.io using passport: https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio

Comment: @AbirTaheer Put a answer in please, you did a lot of research, would like to award you bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using a JWT token, separate from this, to solve the issue of the socket.io session.s

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it has to do with the signup function? I think there's no sign up option for first-comers. Try making `if (user)` -> `if (!user)`